# How to do a preg_replace() to remove anything except for "Post" or "Posts"?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a string that returns various stuff like numbers, spaces, etc. All I want from it is just "Post" or "Posts". Can someone give me an example of how to do this in PHP?

Comment: This might be easier to accomplish if you just search for the presence of either "Post" or "Posts" using `stripos` rather than `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, use `preg_match` like so:

```
$myData = "There are 15 posts in this forum.";
preg_match("/Posts?/", $myData, $results);
if($results[0][0] === "Posts") {
     // It was "posts"
} else {
     // Assume it was "post"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$post = preg_replace('/.*(Posts?).*/', '$1', $string);
```

If you just want to detect if the word `Post` is in the string, then using `strpos()` would be far more efficient.

```
if (strpos($string, 'Post') !== FALSE) {
   ... Post  is present ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are testing to see if the string contains the word "Posts" then you could use something like this:

```
if (preg_match("/Posts/i", $theString)) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading that correctly, it seems that you don't need the string Post/Posts, just if they exist. If that is the case the fastest way would be to use the [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function. You could use it as follows:

```
if( strpos($haystack,"Post") !== false ) {
    //You get here if Post or Posts was found.
}
```